# How can I schedule a program kill at ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

Is there something like `$ sudo shutdown -P 1:00` to kill a process at a certain time?

Comment: May you can use crontab?

Comment: Usually when I see someone ask "how do I repeatedly kill something", I find it best to then ask "why is it coming back from the dead?" (aka what is the problem that you need to kill the software repeatedly for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! It is called `at` and it is an extremely powerful function for one-time jobs without using `cron`.

Example:

```
% TZ=Asia/Tokyo at -f ls -t 202101271336
```

This will run `ls` at 2021-01-27 at 13:36 Tokyo time. Just replace `ls` with your kill function, or a script, or whatever. If you want to repeat it, then use `cron` like the other commenter suggested. Although killing things this way is ... an interesting strategy.

Check your queued jobs with `atq`.